# Failed to complete installation upgrade

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I was using Ubuntu 13.04 and tried upgrading to 13.10. It finished the downloading pretty well and was in the installation phase when power suddenly went off. Now i have a partial installation in that some programs are not running and some graphics are just invincible. Note: I don't have a backup of my 13.04. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu 13.10 .iso and make either a bootable DVD or USB Flash Drive to install from, then during install select the Upgrade existing Ubuntu option from the list and hopefully it will use what is available to give you a fully working installation...